# perl syntax highlighting disactivated

Tags: syntax-highlighting, perl

I'm using emacs for perl scripting and for some unknown reason the syntax highlighting is inactivated when opening new or existing scripts.

I'm wondering if I press a key unknowingly that disactivates it.

Currently my only option is to close emacs and start a new session.

Is there a way to reactivate it?

Not sure which mode is providing the highlighting.

Thanks

Comment: Use `C-h v major-mode` to find out what major mode handles your perl sources.

Comment: @choroba thanks. This works in a non perl buffer. In a perl buffer however it seems to provide help for the syntax at the cursor position. But found it through describe-variable and results in **cperl-mode**

Answer (score 2):

You can always turn syntax highlighting back on using `M-x font-lock-mode`. Using the same command a second time will turn it back off. If you've got it bound to a key that you've inadvertently pressed, use `Ctrl+h w font-lock-mode` to find which key it's bound to.

If you want to set font-lock-mode permanently for cperl, you can do so by setting either `cperl-font-lock` or `cperl-hairy` to `t`. The former sets only syntax highlighting; the latter also sets some other values - check the info for the variable for more information.

Comment: thanks! turning this mode off and on works. I don't have a binding for font-lock-mode though, so probably something else is happening. But at least I should be able to enable it again.

Comment: I've occasionally had syntax highlighting fail when I've been working with very large scripts. In most cases turning it off and on again has worked. Maybe it's the same issue.

Comment: ai, it happened again and unfortunately toggling `M-x font-lock-mode` did not work...

Comment: Turn `debug-on-error` on and try it again. The issue here isn't that font-lock-mode isn't on  - it's that it fails with this particular file. Debugging will help you figure out why.

Comment: Second though: What happens if you run `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer`? Preferably with `debug-on-error` on.

Comment: thanks. I've enabled the debugger and tried `font-lock-fontify-buffer`. I'll let you know what happens when the problem reoccurs.

Comment: so finally, I encountered the problem again today. Sorry for the delay. Anyway. The debugger does not yield any information. the `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer` command results in coloring the shebang or commands and the values of strings.